# htaccess force ssl with hidden variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index2.php?pn=$1 [L]
```

It redirects urls and works well. For example instead of mydomain.com/index2.php?pn=home the browser loads mydomain.com/home.  My issue is I need SSL on every page.  I've tried many htaccess ssl force options to no avail.

Thanks for the help.

jk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you the following rule?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried it before and after my code and it still will not redirect correctly.  Any other ideas?